# Vmware Fusion settings and OSX

Tags: vmware-fusion, osx-el-capitan

Some of the settings for VMware Fusion 8 on OSX don't seem to be working.

1. If I go to settings->Keyboard & Mouse and set Mac Profile to default, and also check Enable Mac OS Host Keyboard Shorcuts, I cannot copy and paste text from the host machine to the guest machine.
2. I have tried very many different settings with display in an attempt to get the resolution of the guest machine to change, there is never any change. I just want the font size to be smaller than ~ 32px. The VM console also will not allow me to scroll up or down using my mouse.

The guest OS is a Centos 7 image. Is there something I'm missing here? I have gone onto the guest machine and installed open-vm-tools with yum.